# Perl to match specific words in array

Tags: regex, perl

need help in a quick perl script. I have lot of configs on a Linux box and I'm using grep, egrep etc and storing it in a array.

printing the array  `@unix` gives below result :

```
abc-xyz-1a.conf-virtual Hey {
abc-xyz-1a.conf-virtual How {
abc-xyz-1a.conf-virtual where {
abc-xyz-1b.conf-virtual Hey {
abc-xyz-1b.conf-virtual How {
abc-xyz-1b.conf-virtual where {
```

Now if you look at this output, I am looking for a regex to give me 2 possible things.

First is the device name, here we can see there are 2 kinda device name

```
abc-xyz-1a  and abc-xyz-1b
```

Second there are different kind of name after the word virtual "Hey", "How" , "Where" etc.

I need to extract these value in a variable which am not able to do .

FYI , when i print print `unix[0]` , it gives the first whole line i.e.

```
abc-xyz-1a.conf-virtual Hey {
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to match specific words that are in a preset array, or match words that occur at a certain place in the input and put them into an array? It seems that both solutions so far do the latter, but your question suggests the first case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a hash table to record those information, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %record;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, undef, $val) = split /\.|\s+/;
    push @{$record{$key}}, $val;
}

print Dumper(\%record);

__DATA__
abc-xyz-1a.conf-virtual Hey {
abc-xyz-1a.conf-virtual How {
abc-xyz-1a.conf-virtual where {
abc-xyz-1b.conf-virtual Hey {
abc-xyz-1b.conf-virtual How {
abc-xyz-1b.conf-virtual where {
```

---

Testing:

```
$ perl t02.pl 
$VAR1 = {
          'abc-xyz-1a' => [
                            'Hey',
                            'How',
                            'where'
                          ],
          'abc-xyz-1b' => [
                            'Hey',
                            'How',
                            'where'
                          ]
        };
```

Comment: Use perl function `grep`

Comment: @ZhangChn For what purpose?

Comment: @LeeDuhem... I got a question when am print the value its print all the 3 values " Hey , How Where " . What would be the syntax to read first second and thrid element???

Comment: @user3185596 `$record{'abc-xyz-1a'}->[0]` or `$record{'abc-xyz-1a'}[0]` will give you `Hey`, you could access other data in `%record` by similar ways. Please read `perlref` for further details.

Comment: @LeeDuhem..Thanks again

Comment: @LeeDuhem `grep` function is more concise, compressed and readable than a loop especially for(, but not limited to) the case of filtering a lot of strings with a regex predicate.

Comment: @ZhangChn Likely there are much more work to do in that loop body, not just filtering. I do not believe using `grep` in this case could lead to more readable code, unless you introduce some auxiliary subroutines.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
   my ($device, $word) = /([a-z0-9-]+)\Q.conf-virtual\E\b(.+)\b/;
   print "Device: $device -- Word: $word\n";
}

__DATA__
abc-xyz-1a.conf-virtual Hey {
abc-xyz-1a.conf-virtual How {
abc-xyz-1a.conf-virtual where {
abc-xyz-1b.conf-virtual Hey {
abc-xyz-1b.conf-virtual How {
abc-xyz-1b.conf-virtual where {
```

Regular Expression breakdown:

```
# capture 1, match one or more of a lowercase letter, number, or dash
([a-z0-9-]+)

# \Q disables meta characters
# match .conf-virtual literally
# \E enables meta characters again 
\Q.conf-virtual\E

# \b word boundary
# (.+) capture 2, match one or more of anything
# \b word boundary
\b(.+)\b
```